# Anything more would be cruelty

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

What does **"Anything more would be cruelty"** mean when it is said by a doctor? Does it mean *"we can not do anything more for him"* or *"anything more than this would be illegal"*?

Context:

**Doctor:** You'd best stay with him. Keep him as comfortable as you can.

**Man:** But he... he's gone the color of brass. Isn't there...

**Doctor:** I have administered some laudanum to help him sleep. Anything more would be cruelty.

Comment: Any medical intervention would be useless and would cause discomfort needlessly.

Comment: I would be more interested in what "Heep him as comfortable as you can" or "help hip sleep" means. Jes' kiddin'!

Comment: Sometimes, dragging out an illness is unkind. So doing more would be cruelty, not kindness.